# Long term management of AC joint injury

Tags: injury, shoulder, scapula, pain-management

What is the best way to deal with AC joint injury (Grade III) in the longer run, if the surgeon suggests that surgery is not a worthwhile option for the degree of injury I have? I regularly feel mild pain in the shoulder around the scapula even after several months of the injury. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to manage this pain well?

I have experienced that stretching elastic bands and lifting small weights do provide some relief for a short duration when done after several days. Also, ice packs do help in subsiding the pain. I could not find much literature on pain management related to AC joint injury.